# Flume... How to configure source and sink in different VMs?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I wish to configure the avro SOurce in VM1 and Sink in VM2.

The Source should be able to connect to the channels in VM2 and channels will send data to sink in VM2. How should I proceed to configure this?

Please help.

Comment: Can  you please tell what are you trying to achieve here?
If you are trying to move data from avro client then you need to bind avro client to ip and port and then make avro source to listen to same.

Comment: I am trying to seggregate Source and sink to different VMs. The source will be on VM1 and sink will be in VM2. The source will send data to VM2 and the channel in VM2 will listen to the source

Comment: Channel used will be of same machine where agent is run(if you use say memchannel or filechannel ) . Your source and sink can be any host and port in network in case of avro or thrift sink